# Schedule email account settings using Provesioning profile iOS

Tags: ios, email-client, mdm

Is it possible to schedule turn on/off setting using MDM.

I just want emails of some specific account in specific duration of time i.e 8:00 am to 1:00 PM

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I tried to answer your question, but frankly, it's quite vague. It's not clear what does it mean "turn on/off setting" and "schedule email account settings".

Comment: Thanx @VictorRonin I just want emails of some specific account in specific duration of time i.e 8:00 am to 1:00 PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install/uninstall a profile using MDM. This profile could be Email or Exchange account.

So, generally speaking, your server can have a job which will install/uninstall such profile. However, ti will be a little bit more than turning it on/off. It will completelly remove an account (including removing all emails on a device).

If your server "knows" account passwords, you can push update to a profile which with correct or incorrect password, which will allow/prevent user from receiving/sending emails.

**Update1**

BTW. If you are hosting email or exchange server, you can terminate connection to it and allow/deny access to it based on current time.

Comment: Can we not change its setting?

Comment: There is no setting which gives exactly what you are looking for (as example 8AM to 8PM email access). So, you will have to change configuration profile other settings to get what you need.

Comment: Also, take a look at my update